# What integrated circuit has the capability to control the connection between two I/O pins for signal transmission

Tags: fpga

I am working on an educational project to play around with computer networking and communication.

I won't be using any official networking protocols and I'm fine with that.

I would like to build a sort of network switch which has the capability to route different nodes to one another.

I'd like to find a single chip solution that has 100's of I/O pins, and has the ability to connect any of these I/O pins to any other using some sort of protocol.

So, if I wanted node 4 to talk to node 20, and node 4 uses pins 20-25, and node 20 uses pins 100-105, pins 20-25 would get connected to 100-105.

At present, it would be possible to use an Atmel microcontroller with 100's of I/O's and turn on and off a pair of transistors for each data line to allow the communication to occur.

However, I would rather save myself the hassle of a thousand transistors and would rather drop hundreds on a single chip solution for the task.

So, have any of you seen the chip I'm describing? If so, what sort of chips should I be looking for, and should I pay special attention to features relevant to the signal transmission aspect of the circuit (parasitic capacitance, inductance, etc.)?

EDIT:
Although crosspoint switches would be nice, I can't find a lot of them with the hundreds of channels I'm looking for. An FPGA would be a nice solution, but I don't know if these devices would allow me to do the routing I wish to do.

Comment: "crosspoint switch"

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the signals you want to switch? What is your actual requirement for the number of channels?

Comment: Actual is 100 channels at 100mbps. I asked more broadly in case someone else was interested.

Comment: @pericynthion I looked that up and it seems really promising. I really appreciate the info! Now I just need to compare what's available, and if I can daisy-chain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally this is called a "crossbar switch", which is an actual category of parts you can buy.

The most applicable *general-purpose* parts to *improvise* one from would be CPLDs and FPGAs, though you'd be seriously underusing the capability of the latter.

An MCU is generally **NOT** a good choice for this task except in low speed circumstances, as MCU I/Os could only be universally bridged by the involvement of software, which introduces latency, sample rate limitations, and likely sampling jitter.  The exception might be certain MCU's that have a degree of almost FPGA-like arbitrary I/O pin mapping, though that is generally to put any functional block on any pin - any ability to directly map one I/O pin to another would be a sort of side effect.

Comment: Can I use the FPGA alone? I was excited at first when you brought up crosspoint switches, but this faded as I realize they don't make 128*128 switches very common. The only source I could find has discontinued their chip. On the other hand FPGA's are very commonly and cheaply found with hundreds of IO's.

Comment: Essentially yes; SRAM based FPGAs require a distinct ROM to load the bitstream from, but there are those available that include that in the package, and other types of FPGAs that are natively based on non-volatile storage methods.  You probably do want to pick on that is reprogrammable (vs permanent fuses) however, or you'll get very good at hot air rework.  You can also include logic or even a soft core processor in the FPGA to handle setting the switch based on complex inputs from a user or other system.  But FPGAs are not cheap.

Comment: You've just solved all my current problems and sent me to FPGA land where I will encounter new problems. That's less problems than I'd have in crosspoint switch land with my 200 IO requirement. Will the FPGA allow me to route directly, or will I have to read at one IO and write to another IO dictated by the clock speed of the FPGA?

Comment: Doing a direct "combinatorial" path between an input and an output would be unusual, but it may be supported by at least some FPGAs.  Typically there are efforts to minimize the combinatorial and routing delay between clocked elements.  but available internal clock rates may well be fast enough that having a registered path would be hard to externally notice.  You probably want to experiment some with a candidate FPGA family on an eval board or at least verify the tools will compile your design before you commit to designing around it.